# document.getElementById('someid') not working with locker service

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service

2 days back when we enabled locker service document.getElementById('someid') was working. All of a sudden it stopped working and now gives undefined. i can see the div whose property i need to modify from browser F12. Please help.

Comment: I assume this is with LockerService activated based on the tags. Does the code work with LockerService off? Do you have any example code to look at? In general document.getElementById is functional, but there may be corner cases we missed.

Comment: Hi Trevor, Yes the code works fine when locker service is off, when locker service is on, the line document.getElementById('maindatascreen').style.setProperty('display', 'none'); does not work. when i check document.getElementById('maindatascreen') in console log, it gives undefined.

Comment: There are several examples of getElementById working inside LockerService. If you have in markup: `<div id="maindatascreen"/>` then document.getElementById("maindatascreen") will return that element. If you edit your question and include your markup I can help debug it.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing the same in the *afterRender* function in the *renderer* file.

```
({
afterRender: function(component, helper) {
    this.superAfterRender();
    //YOUR CODE
}
```

})